# English Language and Usage: Q and A in English only

Tags: discussion

Can you point out where is the requirement or discussion that questions and answers should be in English? I didn't find it in the FAQ (except "Languages other than English (including translation)") or About.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking if you are allowed to ask questions in a language other than English?  This is an English language site, so no.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to explain, why people on the other site, which is similar to English, except the subject is the other language, are allowed to ask questions only on that language.

Comment: Well conceivably one could ask questions about English in another language, but… best to disallow such questions on this site. :-)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'm talking about this exact site, which is English.SE, and both @Kosmonaut and @ShreevatsaR attempted to answer me. Specifically I implied "What languages one's allowed to ask questions in?" That's all. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There's also a blog entry about that here:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Jeff, OK. English.SE is something different than SU, SO, SF et cetera. Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

**Because English is the language that most users speak.**

I’m slightly confused by some other comments/answers.  There seem to be two different questions that are getting conflated:

1. What can one talk *about* on a site?
2. What languages can one *use* on a site?

These aren’t necessarily the same!  This site is about English — but one could also have a site for discussing Greek in English, or for discussing English in Russian, or…  And most of the Stack Exchange sites aren’t even about a language at all, of course.

However, it’s *also* the case that the working language of this site is English.  Why?  Jeff has argued [elsewhere](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) for why they are trying to keep the Stack Exchange sites monolingual for the moment.  And English is the language that most people in this community speak best — so English is the language we choose.